# Can I call a door to the left 'left door'?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Can I call a door to the left 'left door'?

The word left is also an adjective, and it doesn't sound wrong to me, but I wanted to make sure.

Let's say I'm in a room, and there's a door to my left and another to my right. A man opens the door to my left and comes in. Can I say that the man came in from the 'left door'?

Comment: Anything on **your** left can be a left x. We often say: left-hand door, in fact.

Comment: Of course, from his perspective he came in through the right door.

Comment: @Acccumulation Unless he meant to go to another room, then it's the wrong door.

Comment: @Barmar, in which case, he probably then left via the right door since the right door was the wrong door and the left door was the right door, and once he'd tried all the doors, there were no doors left...  English is funny sometimes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*He came in from the left door* makes sense, but does sound a bit unnatural to me. I would say one of the options below first (probably depending on how exactly the doors were configured). See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=left%20door%2Cleft-hand%20door%2Cdoor%20on%20the%20left&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleft%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20-%20hand%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoor%20on%20the%20left%3B%2Cc0).

- He came in from the left-hand door.
- He came in from the door on the left.

Comment: As an aside, this reminded me of the "none pizza, left beef" meme https://www.buzzfeed.com/andyneuenschwander/hbd-none-pizza-with-left-beef

Comment: Or "left-side door".

Comment: "He came from the the door on the left" would be the most common usage -- although "he came from the middle door" feels slightly more natural for some reason, possibly because "left" and "right" have alternate meanings that could confuse the situation depending on context?

Comment: @BrianLacy I wouldn't agree. I wouldn't use "He came from" in that manner. I might say "He came from the gym," but I wouldn't use it to describe how "he" entered the room without "in."

Comment: (Note that “left-hand door” can also refer to the side of the door on which the hinges are set.)

Comment: +1, though I think it's a bit more natural to say "came in *through* [such-and-such door]" rather than "came in *from* [such-and-such door]".

Comment: @ruakh Yeah, probably.

Comment: I was referring to using "the door on the left" being more natural than "the left door". An overall improvement might be "he entered through the door on the left." But this is all getting into much more subjective territory.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds perfectly fine to me. Here's an example from the web:

> We can arrange to close the left door a little bit before the right door. — [Relativity for Everyone: How Space-Time Bends](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xa0YCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22the%20left%20door%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&gbmsitb=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSx93k1Yz3AhUSj4kEHSeRCsUQ6AF6BAgGEAM)

It means exactly what you would want it to mean (assuming everyone is oriented the same way), and could also be used to refer to the left half of a pair of [double doors](https://frenchly.us/why-do-americans-call-double-doors-french-doors/). (And likewise for "right door" but you have to avoid using that in a context where it can be interpreted as meaning the "correct door".)

Comment: this is true, but the context does matter. If, as in Azor's example there is no context beyond the bare statement, then Azor's example wins. In your quoted example, which is perfectly fine, the context was set up earlier and uses "at left/at right" when first establishing the example. (page 22). A minor point, but this is ELL

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use a definite article, so “the left door” would be fine.  “*From left door,” for example, would not be.

A good way to check this is with a Google ngrams search for `left door,the left door`.  This shows that the vast majority of hits for “left door” are part of the phrase “the left door.”  Most of the remainder either put a modifier between “the” and “left,” such as “the ornate left door,” or else are false matches, such as “she left Door County,” or “door on the left, door on the right, ....”

There are a few exceptions, however.  Some forms of writing, particularly accident reports, can be written in a very abbreviated style that eliminates unnecessary words.  This is often called “telegraphic style,” because people used to have to pay by the word to send telegrams and would therefore cut out as many words as they could and still be understood.  In this style of writing, we might expect to see extremely terse phrases such as, “exited left door.”

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, "left door" is fine, but you should consider ambiguities where your left is someone else's right.

- In a car in which all occupants are facing the front of the vehicle, there's no possibility of confusion as to which side is the left (although many writers prefer *driver's side* and *passenger's side*, or *nearside* and *offside*).
- In nautical terminology, *port* and *starboard* are used to refer to the left- and right-hand sides of a vessel to avoid any confusion that may arise from crew members referring to their own left and right.
- When a rail operator needs to refer to the left or right of a train, they may qualify this with "facing the direction of travel".
- When referring to buildings it's highly likely that people will be facing in different directions, so it's helpful to include a reference point such as "facing the exit".